# Multiplications of n matrices(2X2)

Tags: matlab

I want to multiple n matrices(2X2).How to do that.it should start from 1 till nrlayer like M(1)*M(2)*M(3)* till *M(nrlayer)

Comment: Your question looks interesting, but is unclear. Please write it more more clearly, better yet with an example

Comment: If all matrices are 2x2, then, I think, just start multiplying all of them in a for loop. Otherwise, you could have used dynamic programming to determine the order for multiplication. Maybe, something like this: `R=1;for i=1:nrlayer R=R*M{i};`, where each M{i} contains a matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
T=1;
for i=1:nrlayer,
  T=T*M{i}; 
end
```

Comment: and if I want to extract some elements of final T matrix,do I do like   lets say M11=T(11) ?

Comment: Gramoz these kind of questions can be easily solved in google. They are pretty straight forward and MatLab documentation is very good. Please google it first :)

Comment: You want to get a value of the final matrix, right? If that is you question, http://de.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html this tutorial is very helpful.

Comment: Yeha I am alreading checking that one,thank you

Comment: I am having a problem with the code down
   'nrlayer=2
    n=[1.44 1.7]
    d=[1 2]
    eps=[1.2 1.3]
    lambda=400 
    theta=[1 1]
    pol=1 %for TE
    %pol=2 %for TM

    if pol==1
    for t=1:1:nrlayer
    %value1=(8.85418*10^(-12))/(4*pi*10^(-7))
   
    njot(t)=n(t)*cos(theta(t))
    sigma(t)=(2*pi*n(t)*d(t)*cos(theta(t)))/lambda
   
    m11(t)=cos(sigma(t))  
    m12(t)=(i*sin(sigma(t))/njot(t))
    m21(t)=i*njot(t)*sin(sigma(t))
    m22(t)=cos(sigma(t))
    M(t)=[m11(t) m12(t);m21(t) m22(t)]
    end

    M=1;
    for i=1:nrlayer,
    M=M*M{i}; 
    end
'

Comment: The code is quite unreadable. Can you please explain what you want to do, and what the problem is?

Comment: Yeah I tried to put it as a code here but it doesn't work

Comment: The idea is that I must calculate some transmission throu multilayer system.For that I use the Transfer matrix method.It has been long time since I delt with matlab so I completely forgot how to do the stuff.Each layer is represented by a matrix that has 4 elements(it is 2X2). FOr each layer I obtain one 2x2 matrix,and I must multiplicate all these matrix in between.At the end I need to take our each element of the final 2X2 matrix for analysis...

Comment: and now I can't save matrix(1) in the sense that the index will tell me that it is the matrix of the 1st laayer,and after do M=M(1)M(2)M(3)...M(nrlayer).Finally I need to separate the 4 elements of the final M matrix

Comment: http://www.fzu.cz/~kuzelp/Optics/Lecture6.pdf
MY formulas are based here

Comment: Sorry, but i cannot help even that i would like to. I have already removed matlab. The only thing i can suggest try creating small steps till you achieve the desired result. The code looks kind of correct. Might be some small mistake.